# Independent fit and transform for sklearn.manifold SpectralEmbedding

Tags: visualization, manifold

I was trying to use a SpectralEmbedding model to perform dimensionality reduction. And I want to train the model first using some training data and then fit the model on another set of data. However, it seems like there's no independent "transform" function built in the module, which makes this process impossible. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to work around this issue? Thanks a lot!

I looked into some other documents but thus far didn't find anything useful